# How to pipe image from request to pdfkit in node.js?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio, node-pdfkit

First off, I am a total newbie both to Javascript and Node.js, so sorry if my question is stupid.

I am trying to scrape text and images off a website and export it to a pdf using request, cheerio and pdfkit, but I'm having problems.

I am able to scrape the images and save them locally using this:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(body);

        $("#mediatab1 img").each(function(){
        var image= 'http://WWW.WEBSITE.no' + $(this).attr('src');
        images.push(image);
        });

        for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
            request(images[i]).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('images/' + i + '.jpg')); }
```

**BUT! Here's the problem:**

**1. INTENT:** When I try to write the files to the pdf using

```
doc.image('images/0.jpg');
```

all I get is

```
Error: Unknown image format.
    at Function.PDFImage.open (C:\nodejs\node_modules\pdfkit\js\im
age.js:41:15)
    at PDFDocument.module.exports.image (C:\nodejs\node_modules\pd
fkit\js\mixins\images.js:27:26)
    at Request._callback (C:\nodejs\prosjekt.js:29:6)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\nodejs\node_modules\request\reque
st.js:344:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\nodejs\node_modules\request\request
.js:1239:14)
    at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\nodejs\node_modules\request
\request.js:1187:12)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:944:16
```

0.jpg is 0 bytes, so I suspect there is a timing issue here?

**2. INTENT**

I tried to use .pipe instead of saving locally:

```
request(images[i]).pipe(doc.image(images[0]));
```

But all I get is:

```
"Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\nodejs\http:\www.WEBSITE.no\Common\Tools\ImageScaler.ashx?id=c7d73548-8198-4bd1-867d-33fc0dfe73d1&h=4
13'
```

Any idea how to fix this or to solve the problem in any other way?

Here's the whole script:

```
var request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    PDFDocument = require('pdfkit'),
    doc = new PDFDocument,
    fs = require('fs'),
    prompt = require('prompt');
    bilder = [];


    prompt.start();
    prompt.get(['prosjekturl'], function (err, result) {    
    request({url: 'http://www.WEBSITE.no/no/Prosjekter/Prosjekt/?pid=' + result.prosjekturl, encoding:null}, function(err, resp, body){
        if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
        //  console.log(body);

        var $ = cheerio.load(body);

            $("#mediatab1 img").each(function(){
            var bilde = 'http://www.WEBSITE.no' + $(this).attr('src');
            bilder.push(bilde);
            });

            console.log(bilder);
            for(var i = 0; i < bilder.length; i++){
                request(bilder[i]).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('images/' + i + '.jpg'));
            }           

            $("#MiddleRightContainer h1").each(function(){
            var tittel = $(this).text();
            console.log(tittel);
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('pdf/output.pdf'));

            doc.font('fonts/FONT-Regular.ttf');
            doc.fontSize(32);
            doc.text(tittel);

            });

            $("#MiddleRightContainer .user-content p").each(function(){
            var tekst = $(this).text();

            console.log(tekst);
            doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('pdf/output.pdf'));
            doc.fontSize(12);
            doc.text(tekst);


            });

            $("#RightSidebar div.box2").each(function(){
            var fakta = $(this).text();
            console.log(fakta);

            });

            }



doc.end();
            });


            });
```

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

"*PDFKit supports the JPEG and PNG formats*"

[Here](https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/blob/master/lib/image.coffee) you can see it's checking .jpeg and .png extensions. Yours is a .jpg file. I've had trouble with this a few times and this has fixed my issue.

Comment: Tried renaming to .jpeg, but I still get the "Unknown image format" error. The .jpeg files are 0 bytes (when I add "doc.image('images/0.jpg');", if I leave it out, the files are full size).

Comment: I know I've had some trouble with transparent pngs, however that seemed to be due to a problem in old node 0.10.31 (if I'm not mistaken...)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the file loading I suspect that the windows paths can be a problem. Try and use node.js built-in path resolution: https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

When it comes to request and loading images it should not be more than:

```
request({
    url: url,
    // Prevents Request from converting response to string
    encoding: null

}, function (err, response, body) {
    doc.image(body)
})
```

Hope it helps some.